# Unable to pass envionment variables as sensitive fields while calling remote shell script from ExecuteProcess in Apache Nifi

Tags: linux, bash, remote-server, apache-nifi

I am trying to run a remote script through a script in my host environment from the **ExecuteProcess** processor in NiFi. Basically, the shell script in the host server has the ssh string calling the remote server and then calling the script in that remote server. I used `sshpass` package where I saved the password in an environment variable(SSHPASS) and passed that in the ssh string.For more info on sshpass, https://linux.die.net/man/1/sshpass . The host script content is as follows:

```
sshpass -e ssh user@host sh /path-to-script
```

When I passed the host script path to the command property of the ExecuteProcess processor, the result of the processor showed that it didn't login to the remote server. So, after some debugging, I created a user defined property in the processor that specified the **environment variable** *SSHPASS* and its value which is the password of the remote server and then it worked.

I exported the password as an environment variable so that I don't have to pass it as cleartext in the first place. Is there any workaround where I don't have to specify the environment variable value ? Any suggestions on any other method to connect to the remote server and call the script is welcome too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried using the `-f` or `-d` options for `sshpass`? They allow you to read the password from a file or file descriptor respectively. This way you can use OS-level access controls to restrict access to the file rather than having the password in an environment variable which other users or processes may be able to access.

I can investigate further why the executed process apparently did not have access to the environment variable value if those options are not sufficient.

Comment: Thanks Andy. That works. I am looking to use SSH keys instead which would be more secure. Thank for your help.